# Compiling a list based upon table contents

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a table, similarly structured to the one in the screenshot below. In this table, I have tasks to be completed in column B, the days these tasks will be completed in column C:W and who will be completing this task in column A.

[image: https://snag.gy/lGZnYy.jpg]

What I wish to do is be able to create lists that will reflect the data in this table, so in row 1:1, you would have the names of the people in this table, and in column A, you would have the `WEEKNUM`, and within the contents of each list a list would be compiled based upon what that person had to do that week. I'd also want to include a `UNIQUE` function so duplicate results in the same week are not repeated.

Could someone offer some help with this?

Comment: are you sure you want weeknum not weekday?

Comment: Hi @player0

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oz4ULeq2BMQCQi08bqb6RGgTgjLIaw364cTb7J8W6fk/edit?usp=sharing

I have created a results tab which I have given the example of what I would want to achieve from this weeks data.

RE: Weeknum. I'm wanting to create a weekly list of tasks. I presumed a part of the functions used would be a matching of WEEKNUM of the date in C2:W2 to WEEKNUM(TODAY()).

Answer (score 0):

paste in **A1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(INDIRECT("Table!"&ADDRESS(3, MATCH(WEEKNUM(HLOOKUP(TODAY(), Table!2:2, 1, 0), 21), 
 WEEKNUM(Table!2:2, 21), 0), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(Table!A1:A)+1, MATCH(WEEKNUM(
 HLOOKUP(TODAY(), Table!2:2, 1, 0), 21), WEEKNUM(Table!2:2, 21), 0)+6, 4))<>"", 
 Table!A3:A&"♦", ),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦"))))))
```

paste in **A2** cell and drag to the right:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF(INDIRECT("Table!"&ADDRESS(3, MATCH(WEEKNUM(HLOOKUP(TODAY(), Table!2:2, 1, 0), 21), 
 WEEKNUM(Table!2:2, 21), 0), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(COUNTA(Table!$A1:$A)+1, MATCH(WEEKNUM(
 HLOOKUP(TODAY(), Table!2:2, 1, 0), 21), WEEKNUM(Table!2:2, 21), 0)+6, 4))<>"",
 Table!$A3:$A&"♠"&Table!$B3:$B&"♥", ),,999^99)),,999^99), "♥")))), "♠")),
 "select Col2 where Col1='"&A1&"'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is great. Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to add some more functionality/search functions alongside this.

On the same file, you can see I have altered some of the data so it mirrors by actual spreadsheet closer (I can't share the actual sheet due to sensitive information).

You will see there are now strings of 1's, which represent the start and end of a deadline. There are two things I would like to achieve.

Comment: 1) Find the given deadline for a particular task. i.e, what date does the final '1' appear in. Unless it makes the function overly complex, I'd also like for recurring tasks (like seen in 4:4) to have the first deadline appear rather than the last. So you can see the first deadline for this task is 13/05/19, so this date would be returned, and once this deadline has exceeded, the next deadline for that task (24/05/19) would be given.

Comment: 2) I would like to be able to give a category for a task. You can see the tasks are now within subheaders. On the results table, I'd like to be able to search for the tasks in that list and find the category this task falls within.

You will see on the SS in the results tab I have added the two new columns and the results we'd achieve.

Appreciate your help as always!